# fit large number into an array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I have an `array` of `10^5` size. say `array[100000]`.
I have to insert data into that array like indexing for fast retrieval. like `array[index] = value`.

i.e., 124th element [123 index] has some number 23423423 as the value, so I put

```
array[123] = 23423423;
```

so that I can refer to that value with the index `123`.

Now the problem is I have some index value upto `10^9` but array size can't hold that much big number, so is there any way to fit all index and there values into the array.

I use C as my language.

Comment: See hash table. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: You will need to either find a "sparse array" implementation, or a "map" implementation. Either of these will have a slightly different syntax from normal array indexing but will only allocate storage for what you actually use, not the entire 10^9 space. They will internally manage indexing to be quick based on some kind of hash.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), i.e. perhaps you're approaching whatever you're trying to do incorrectly, but, without telling us what that is, we can't really help (but a hash table may indeed be the correct answer to the question not asked).

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen I read that wiki before but I was unable to find good hash function, I used mod operator but there are chances of collision, please guide me some more with some hash functions

Comment: @mah I used Map in C++, but that is making my code working very slow :( I am looking for sparse array.. thank you

Comment: Generic collision free hash functions do not exist... Either one has to search a perfect hash functions for the fixed input, or prepare for collisions. When I'm lazy, I often use crc32 as the base function.

Comment: @avinashse maybe you can describe the actual problem? Why do you need the massive array? also describe the performance criteria

Comment: @avinashse For sparse array design, please tell us about the nature of the indexes: how many (relative to maximum index value), distribution, ...

Comment: @meaning-matters Indexes are integers only upto 10^9 numbers.

Comment: @claptrap I am solving a live contest problem on `http://www.codechef.com/JAN14/problems/FGFS`, where I implemented this problem with multimap and map for hashing purpose, but First I was getting SIGSEGV, after a lot of SIGSEGV , I handled that now getting TLE's. so need some better approach then using map. so I came to ask here finally thinking of the problem stated above. Its not the rule to get help for live contest, but instead of asking help I need help for my optimization.

Comment: @avinashse Of course I mean: How many will you store at the same time, roughly?  And you did not say anything about distribution yet either: Are these indexes random, appear in groups, or appear in some other ordered way?  Now don't just say 'random' if you don't know!  It's very important that you know the nature of your data for choosing algorithms to process/store it.

Comment: @meaning-matters User will enter two numbers(a,b) in which first one i.e., `a`, I am considering index and other number `b` as its value. now user will give 10^5 inputs and and `1 <= a , b <=10^9`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only adding new value into your table, and never remove, you can use multiprobation hash table. See my implementation of this: http://olegh.cc.st/src/words.c.txt
There is implemented "double hashing" algorithm (some kind of multiprobation).

It has been written for another purposes, an hold in the table text words, not numbers.
But I think, you can easy customize this code for your tasks.